# X-Frame options sameorigin issue

Tags: wordpress, apache, amazon-web-services, httpd.conf, mautic

I need to show a mautic form on my wordpress website. Hosting environment is AWS Lightsail. Form is showing properly but when click on submit button, it is not submitting and page keeps as it is. When i checked the developer console of Chrome browser, i could see this.

```
Refused to display 'mydomainip/form/submit?formId=1' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

I discovered for apache httpd.conf file in AWS's apache. In the header module section, I could see the current code is,

```
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
```

So i changed it to,

```
X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://mymauticdomainip.com/
```

But still it not works. I'm really stuck here and please someone help me to solve this.

Comment: did you restart the server?

Comment: Yes, i did restart the server

Comment: Still i'm stuck at this point

Comment: Check in Chrome page headers to see if that header works as rxpected. Maybe something else is changing it, from .htaccess or higher up in AWS.

Comment: I can see this message in chrome network panel's headers section - "Provisional headers are shown". I assume this shows due to my pending request.

Comment: Provisional Headers also can mean your browser is using its internal cache to fulfill the request. Clear your browser cache?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - I did a cache clear and tried. Still it's not working. I found a new fact in another similar question of Stackoverflow. It has mentioned that always Chrome blocks this X-Frame options allow rule and better to use "Content Security Policy" concept. Any idea on that?

Comment: Can i apply Content Security Policy rule in apache to solve this?

Comment: @CodeCanyon you can apply any header, a httpd header is just text, Apache httpd does not care about it if you set it right or not, because it is a client interpreted thing.

Answer (score 0):

Might be nothing, but on the google cloud I went to /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf and changed it to this, now it works:

```
<IfVersion >= 2.4.7 >
    Header always setifempty X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM https://example.com"

</IfVersion>
<IfVersion < 2.4.7 >
    Header always merge X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM https://example.com"
</IfVersion>
```